# How to correctly use AND operator in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python code where I am trying to read a csv file using pandas.

Once I have read the csv, the user is asked for input to enter the first name and I filter the records and show only the matching records.

Code :

```
# importing the module
import pandas as pd
  
# read specific columns of csv file using Pandas
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Extension\firefox_extension\claimant_record.csv', usecols = ['ClaimantFirstName','ClaimantLastName','Occupation'])
print(df)

required_df_firstName = input("Enter First Name of Claimant: ")
select_df = df[df['ClaimantFirstName'] == required_df_firstName]
print(select_df)
```

Issue :
There are multiple records matching with first name so I want the user to be able to narrow down the result using first and last name and I am not able to properly write the AND condition.

What I have tried so far:

```
select_df = df[df['ClaimantFirstName'] == required_df_firstName]and df[df['ClaimantLastName'] == required_df_lastName]
```

Comment: Please post a sample data frame for test. Just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to check more than one condition at once.

Here's how it would work:

```py
import pandas as pd

# add sample data
data = {'ClaimantFirstName': ["Jane", "John"], "ClaimantLastName": ["Doe", "Doherty"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# filter by name
required_df_firstName, required_df_lastName = "John", "Doherty"
select_df = df.loc[(df['ClaimantFirstName'] == required_df_firstName) & (df['ClaimantLastName'] == required_df_lastName), ['ClaimantFirstName', 'ClaimantLastName']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `isin`

```
#required_df_firstName = input("Enter First Name of Claimant: ")
#notice the input would be list type , like ['a','b']
select_df = df[df['ClaimantFirstName'].isin(required_df_firstName)]
```